# How to reuse a code which is slightly different

Tags: java, c#, logic

I'm having some difficulties about how to *correctly* design and implement two methods.

I have 2 methods, A and B. Method A does 2 things and method B does only 1 thing. One of the things that method A does is the same as what method B does, so it is very reasonable to call method B from within a method A.

Now the problem is that both methods need to send exactly one email to a user. When I invoke A, I want to receive 1 email and when I invoke B, I also want to get 1 email. This means that if I call method B inside A, I will now get 2 mails while doing 1 action (= invoking A). To make it even more tempting to simply include B in A, the set up procedure is truly the same for both methods and so instead of redoing the set up in the B, I could simply call method B with these set up data from A. But I have no setup data to provide when calling the B directly and so in this case I'd need to do the setup anyway.

What is the best approach to solve such a problem? Should I:

1. Add a parameter to method B in which I will say whether it should send the email or not and another parameters for the setup data
2. Keep the two methods separated, because method B is not doing *exactly* the same thing in the two contexts
3. ... other suggestions?

PS. I'm not sure if stackoverflow is actually suitable for such a question, let me know if there's a better stackexchange platform for this.

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you split out the functionality a little further.

Currently you have two methods that might be described something like this:

```
void MethodA()
{
    DoThing1();
    DoThing2();
    SendEmail();
}

void MethodB()
{
    DoThing1();
    SendEmail();
}
```

So one fairly simple answer is to extract the actual functional bits out of the two methods into methods of their own and leave behind a shell similar to the above.  Each of the `DoThingX` methods can return whatever it is you need for building the email, etc.

Of course if the `DoThingX` methods are really small - a couple of lines or so, for instance - then it might not make sense to break them out this way.

Comment: Yes, sounds very reasonable and I think this is what I will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is truly on-topic either. That said...

It seems to me that "sending email" is one of the things that is included in the method B work that method A needs done. As such, why not just implement it in method B? Then method A gets it for free when it calls method B.

If the exact contents of the email are different depending on whether method A was called or not, then sure…you can add a parameter to method B to customize the email in some way.

Finally, you're pretty vague on the details. It's not really clear just how much code you're saving by calling method B from method A. If it's significant, then I'm a strong proponent of code sharing like this. But if we're just talking a single statement, well...that seems less worth bothering with; maybe just putting that same single statement in each method is better.

Sorry for the vague answer. GIGO. :)

Comment: The content of the email is different depending on which method is sending it. Another idea I had was to create a method C where I do the setup and then simply call C in the beginning of both methods. In this scenario I would only repeat around 3-4 lines of code in A and so I think it is reasonable to let them be two different methods. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the return of the methods for the content of our email:

```
private String funcA() {
    // foo
    return "Mail from funcA";
}

private String funcB() {
    funcA();      // ignoring the return value here, we later return our on
    // foo
    return "Mail from funcB";   // our own return
}
```

Then you send the email outside of these functions (JUST EXAMPLE CODE):

```
private void mainFunc() {
    String mail = condition ? funcA() : funcB();

    sendMail(mail);
}
```

Comment: How can you ignore the return value of funcA() if you call it from funcB()?

Comment: @Tarek Simply by typing it like I did above. If you check / save the return val, it looks like `String resultFromA = funcA();` but a sole call `funcA()` ignores the return val (ignores meaning, you don't do anything with it).

Comment: Very good idea, though for my current project I think it'd just add extra complexity. I have not described my problem in a great detail and so your solution would just add extra complexity to the class/project. The best solution for me is the one provided by kiedysktos and @Corey. Either way, thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I have two ideas:

- create C method that represents common functionality of A and B, and invoke C in A and B with different parameters
- invoke B inside A, but extract mailing functionality alone to separate method C

To clarify the first idea:

```
methodA() {
        firstAction();
        secondAction(Parameter parameterFromA);
        }

methodB() {
        secondAction(Parameter parameterFromB);
        }
```

Comment: I very much like your first idea. I was thinking that I'll put setup in the method C and let the A and B be two different methods because this way it is more readable and I will only repeat 3-4 lines of code. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Well, in general avoiding code repeating is good practice. When I see repeated code in my program, I always consider extracting it to separate method. If I helped, please mark √.

Comment: I have already marked the other answer, both were very helpful, but unfortunately I can't mark two answers as answers

Comment: that's OK, initially I thought you marked none of them. Good luck :)